# python datetime.strftime does not support japanese?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x

I have a problem that following code causes a encoding error:
This problem happens when pass a japanese including string to strftime.

This is caused on python repl on cmd.exe.
Is this problem a bug of python?

```
import datetime
d = datetime.datetime.now()
d.strftime("%y年")
```

Error message:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'locale' codec can't encode character '\u5e74' in position 2: Illegal byte sequence
```

Python 3.6.5
Windows10 1803

Comment: For this simple example you could do `d.strftime("%y") + '年'`

Comment: Or `'{}年'.format(d.strftime('%y'))`

Answer (score 1):

It works after adding the encoding in your script.

**Ex:**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import datetime
d = datetime.datetime.now()
print( d.strftime("%y 年") )
```

**Output:**

```
18 年
```

Comment: I am not sure...repl site is blocked for me here

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3.6+, using f-string:

```
import datetime
d = datetime.datetime.now()
y = d.strftime("%y")
assert f'{y}年' == '18年'
```