# Transform string of date time to datetime format (Japanese characters)

Tags: python, datetime

I have a string of `datetime` like so `2020/10/26 7:56:35 午後 GMT+9` and I'd like to change that string into `datetime` format.
Currently I'm using `strptime()` method with the format text is `%Y-%m%d %I%M%S %p GMT 9` but it's wrong. Is it fine for have japanese inside `datetime` string?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python datetime.strftime does not support japanese?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50742361/python-datetime-strftime-does-not-support-japanese)

Comment: it's the opposite of my question.  I turn a datetime format into string while I want to change from string to datetime format.  I thought my problem is finding the correct format text to pass on the ```strptime()``` function.

Comment: You can only have Japanese inside the format string is if it matches that in the string you are trying to parse with `strptime()` — so add the `午後` to it.

Comment: did you mean `%Y/%m/%d %I:%M:%S %p GMT+9`? the strptime directive has to match all characters, e.g. also the slashes, dots etc.

Comment: @martineau: if I get this right, 午後 is japanese PM, so including it literally in the formatting directive will give a wrong result (hour=7 instead of 19).

Comment: @MrFuppes yep, 午後 is PM in Japanese, I guesss I have to get rid of that and change it to AM/PM instead before passing in ```strptime()``` function

Comment: You should replace `午後` with `PM` I think

Comment: I haven't installed support for Japanese on my system but I guess if that is the case, `strptime` should be able to parse `午後` with `%p`, no?

Comment: @MrFuppes Nope, it's not. I change to PM and it works perfectly

Comment: @MrFuppes: "午後" means "afternoon" — not sure if that corresponds to PM or not — but if it's non-standard the `%p` directive `strptime()` supports will not match it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "pythonic" was to do it without using a third-party module would look something like this.

```
from datetime import datetime


time1="2020/10/26 7:56:35 午後 GMT+9"
#time1="2020/10/26 7:56:35 午前 GMT+9"
#time1="2020/10/26 7:56:35 FM GMT+9"

try:
    parsed_time = datetime.strptime(time1, "%Y/%m/%d %I:%M:%S %p GMT+9")
except ValueError:
    time1PM = time1.replace("午後", "PM")
    try:
        parsed_time = datetime.strptime(time1PM, "%Y/%m/%d %I:%M:%S %p GMT+9")
    except ValueError:
        time1AM = time1.replace("午前", "AM")
        parsed_time = datetime.strptime(time1AM, "%Y/%m/%d %I:%M:%S %p GMT+9")

print(parsed_time)
```

---

Another alternative would be to use a regular expression to replace the Japanese designation with the equivalent substring `strptime()` understands:

```
from datetime import datetime
import re


def multiple_replace(mdict, text):
  ''' Replace keys that match with their corresponding value in dictionary. '''
  regex = re.compile("(%s)" % "|".join(map(re.escape, mdict.keys())))
  return regex.sub(lambda mo: mdict[mo.string[mo.start():mo.end()]], text)

time_str="2020/10/26 7:56:35 午後 GMT+9"
#time_str="2020/10/26 7:56:35 午前 GMT+9"
#time_str="2020/10/26 7:56:35 FM GMT+9"

AMPM = {"午後": "PM", "午前": "AM"}

parsed_time = datetime.strptime(multiple_replace(AMPM, time_str), 
                                "%Y/%m/%d %I:%M:%S %p GMT+9")

print(parsed_time)
```

Comment: that really a nice way to do it instead of the if-else condition. thank you so much.

Comment: Using exceptions in Python is relatively fast, too. Also note the alternative I added doesn't have any if-elses in it either.

Answer (score 4):

Going off of some of the comments posted, you can transform it by using `.replace` to change the AM and PM to English.

```
from datetime import datetime
theTime="2020/10/26 7:56:35 午後 GMT+9"
theTime = theTime.replace("午後", "PM").replace("午前", "AM")
dateTime = datetime.strptime(theTime, "%Y/%m/%d %I:%M:%S %p GMT+9")
print(dateTime)
```

Output:

```
2020-10-26 19:56:35
```

Answer (score 1):

[dateparser](https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) does a good job here:

```
import dateparser # pip install dateparser

# AM:
dateparser.parse("2020/10/26 7:56:35 午前 GMT+9")
Out[4]: datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 26, 7, 56, 35, tzinfo=<StaticTzInfo 'UTC\+09:00'>)

# PM:
dateparser.parse("2020/10/26 7:56:35 午後 GMT+9")
Out[5]: datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 26, 19, 56, 35, tzinfo=<StaticTzInfo 'UTC\+09:00'>)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is just a quick play around with it. You could use the `dictionary` I created **'jap_eng'** to convert/fill with the `PM` and `AM` format.

```
from datetime import datetime

datetime_str = '2020/10/26 7:56:35 午後 GMT+9'

jap_eng = {'午後':'PM', '午前': 'AM'}

full_dt_str = datetime_str[:-8] + jap_eng[datetime_str[-8:-6]]

datetime_object = datetime.strptime(full_dt_str, '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S %p')
```

This will output:

```
datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 26, 7, 56, 35)
```